# Gitlab CI job returns exit status 1 when using output redirection to file

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, stdout, gitlab-ci-runner, tee

We are using shell runner for our Gitlab CI. In our `.gitlab-ci.yml` there is a job which builds our project. I can see the build output in the Gitlab web view but I want to store the build to a log file and upload it as an artifact. The line that builds the project looks like this:

```
emBuild -config "Release" -project "whc_uc1" whc_uc1/whc_uc1.emProject -verbose 2>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath whc_uc1/build.log | Write-Host
```

The problem is the log file is generated with all `stdout` and `stderr` if there are any but the build job returns `ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1`.  This happens of build with and without errors. If I remove the line `2>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath whc_uc1/build.log | Write-Host` then everything works fine.

Another solution that was working but does not output `stderr` in the log file is:

```
|& tee whc_uc1/build.log
```

This solution creates the log file and the build is successful but unfortunately, the log file has no `stderr`.

Comment: May be Write-Host did not return 0, so script fails from gitlab-ci point of view.
Think that echo $? Will never work on gitlab. may be you can try  emBuild .... 2>&1 |Tee-Object ... | Write-Host || true (double pipe), and force it to return true to gitlab-ci. (even if it fail) to see ?  Another lead is some shell do not support |& think to replace  by 2>&1 |

Comment: What's the purpose of `Write-Host`? Can you leave it out in order to collect debugging data?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by installing the new `PowerShell` version 7 now the following `2>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath` now works without any issues.